# Always see NullReference exception in designer with all silverlight business applications in visual studio 2010

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, nullreferenceexception

Starting with the most simple case.

If I press "File->new project->silverlight business application" it opens up to MainPage.xaml saying the message attached at the bottom of this post.

It also does the same thing to any silverlight business application that exists in sourcesafe - this is the first time I've personally needed to work on this technology.

Any advice would be very much appreciated I really need to get started on a project and I feel quite disabled to not have the designer.

Thanks in advance.

> An Unhandled Exception has occured
>
> Click here to reload the designer
>
> Details:
>
> System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightMetadataContext.SilverlightXamlExtensionImplementations.d__8.MoveNext()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildSubsumption()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.SubsumingNamespace(Identifier
>   identifier)    at
>   MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.BuildScope(PrefixScope
>   parentScope, IParseContext context)    at
>   MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertToXaml(XamlElement parent,
>   PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context, IMarkupSourceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.FullParse(Boolean
>   convertToXamlWithErrors)    at
>   MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.get_RootItem()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.Trees.ModifiableDocumentTree.get_ModifiableRootItem()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.MarkupDocumentManagerBase.get_LoadState()
>   at MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem.Load()    at
>   MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()    at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()    at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()    at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView
>   view)    at
>   MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory
>   factory, IsolatedView view)    at
>   MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory
>   factory, IsolatedView view)    at
>   MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()    at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens if you have installed visual studio 2011 developer preview on your pc.

To resolve the error close visual studio and your browsers. Uninstall silverlight (no need to uninstall the sdk just silverlight itself).

Then re-open your project. Follow the instructions and it'll be working just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was struggling from last 3 hours,
I have uninstalled Silverlight and installed Silverlight 4, Now its working fine : )

Answer (score 10):

If you run into this issue, a possible cause is due to you having Microsoft SilverLight version 5.0 installed on your pc versus that of 4.0 (Version: 4.0.50826.0). Remove the copy of SilverLight 5.0. Install the version located at the following link - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=146060
DO NOT INSTALL version 5.0 IF YOU HAVE SDK 3 AND 4. INSTALL MICROSOFT SILVERLIGHT 4.0

Comment: That link points to a download for silverlight 5... but +1 for the fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was struggling from last 3 hours, 
Now its working fine : )

Answer (score -1):

it might be because of your application is developed on Silverlight 5 and you are opening it with the machine having silverlight 4. i am just giving example of 5 and 4. or might be you have not installed the SDK pack of it.