# Why would loading a XAML file faile on a brand new, unaltered Silverlight project?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

Why would loading a XAML file faile on a brand new, unaltered Silverlight project?

This is the first time I have started a silverlight project on the current machine I am on with Visual Studio 2010.  Until now, I have been programing ni ASP.NET.

When I first tried to start a new Silverlight project, I was told I needed to install a fresh copy of Silverlight.  I had to uninstall Silverlight as well as my versions of the Silverlight SDK.  After uninstalling and reinstalling (now I have Microsoft Silverlight  5.1.20513.0 and Silverlight 4 SDK 4.0.50826.0) I was finally able to create a Silverlight Project.  But the XAML code instantly failed to load in the IDE

http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/ASP_DOT_NET%20and%20CSS/outofthegate02_zps0bd33d95.png

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication4.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

</Grid>
```

http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/ASP_DOT_NET%20and%20CSS/outofthegate01_zpse0f20845.png

> ```
>    System.NullReferenceException
> ```
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightMetadataContext.SilverlightXamlExtensionImplementations.d__8.MoveNext()
>      at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildSubsumption()
>      at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.SubsumingNamespace(Identifier identifier)
>      at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.BuildScope(PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context)
>      at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertToXaml(XamlElement parent, PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context, IMarkupSourceProvider provider)
>      at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.FullParse(Boolean convertToXamlWithErrors)
>      at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.get_RootItem()
>      at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.Trees.ModifiableDocumentTree.get_ModifiableRootItem()
>      at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.MarkupDocumentManagerBase.get_LoadState()
>      at MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem.Load()
>      at MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()
>      at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()
>      at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()
>      at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView view)
>      at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
>      at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
>      at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()
>      at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings?

Comment: what does that mean to start a bounty?

Comment: By chance are you using the Visual Studio 2011 Developer Preview?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180828/always-see-nullreference-exception-in-designer-with-all-silverlight-business-app